# How to stop rest of code from executing NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

How would you stop the rest of the code from executing in NodeJs (not termine the application with process.exit() just say this is the last line to be executed).

In regular javascript you have exit(), but that doesnt seem to work in nodejs.

Below is the situation:

```
 connection.query(sql, [req.session.sessionUserPackagePassword] , function(err, rows, fields) {
   if (!err) {
     var userFound = false;
     for(var i=0; i< rows.length; i++) {
       // Make the comparaison case insensitive
       if ((rows[i].deliveredToUser).toLowerCase() == `no`) {
         userFound = true;
         console.log(userFound);
         [...]
     }
}
if (!userFound) {
  res.render('pickup/errorAlreadyDelivered', {});
  // exit here
}

console.log(userFound);

// If the query fails to execute
} else {
  console.log('Error while performing Query.');
  res.render('errorConnection', {});
}
});
connection.end();




  // Update the query to say the box has been delivered to user and specify time



 // Establish the connection
 [...]


    res.render('pickup/openPackageClose', {
          title: '',
          helpButtonURL: '/help/help-dropPackage',
          helpButtonTitle: 'Help'


      });



    });
```

Essentially when this condition is met, I would like the rest of the code not to be executed

```
if (!userFound) {
        res.render('pickup/errorAlreadyDelivered', {});
        // exit here 
}
```

Comment: To stop execution of a block of code, use break;

Comment: Put the code you want to avoid executing inside of the else block.

Comment: Are you sure you want to exit without calling `connection.end()`?

Comment: so i should put connection.end() and then break? connection.end is added below but of course once i put break it wont reach below\

Comment: as the code is in a callback **function** - `return` seems to be a good way to return from the function

Comment: Please indent the code properly so that others (and you too) understand the code better. Currently it looks like you have code like `if(...){...} console.log(userFound); }else{...}` which is certainly not right.

Comment: Thanks for editing your post! There are still some syntax errors in your code. Please try to provide a SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example, see http://sscce.org/). In other words, get rid of all unimportant lines of code and focus on (1) the query and its callback, and (2) whether a user is found or not. Also please take the time to put the code in a linting tool such as eslint.org/demo. This will make it easier to identify/explain the issue, and sometimes you might even find the answer yourself! Then you can apply what you've learned to your problem.

Comment: if you look at the update code in my op i cant exactly add the else condition like this because there's code below the end of the connection, and where the issue is that theres another render below.

Answer (score 1):

`connection.end();` then `return;` seems like it might work for you.

Comment: This assumes that you're in a callback function which seems likely.

Comment: return doesnt end the rest of the code. The issue is that you have another  res.render below, and once that if statement is trigger the last render is render with an error on console saying multiple headers cant be sent.

Comment: I updated the code to provide to try and make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

So based on your comment on my other answer, it sounds like your program structure isn't what I thought it was. This should work:

```
connection.query(sql, [req.session.sessionUserPackagePassword] , function(err, rows, fields) {
   if (!err) {
     var userFound = false;
     for(var i=0; i< rows.length; i++) {
       // Make the comparaison case insensitive
       if ((rows[i].deliveredToUser).toLowerCase() == `no`) {
         userFound = true;
         console.log(userFound);
         [...]
     }
}

if (!userFound) {
  res.render('pickup/errorAlreadyDelivered', {});
  connection.end();
} else { 
  console.log(userFound);
  console.log('Error while performing Query.');
  res.render('errorConnection', {});
  connection.end();
}
```

Comment: Is this what you intend to have happen? Reading this code makes me think there's a problem with the logic.

Comment: let me indent the code and provide an update in my initial post

Comment: Thanks for the update, if you look at the update code in my op i cant exactly add the else condition like this because there's code below the end of the connection, and where the issue is that theres another render below.

Comment: You can render twice in a row in Node?